# Metamask error: Transaction error. exception thrown in contract code

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

I've been successfully compiled and deployed my smart contract `Campaign.sol`. All the functions in my contract can run successfully but as I use my javascript file `RequestRow.js` to call my function `finalizeRequest` Metamask pops up the error `Transaction error. Exception thrown in contract code`
I've googled this error and tried to solve my question by [this](http://Metamask%20error:%20Transaction%20error.%20exception%20thrown%20in%20contract%20code) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38131/why-am-i-getting-transaction-error-exception-thrown-in-contract-code-in-rinkeb). However, they aren't helpful for my error.
Can anyone tells me where did I do wrong in my smart contract. I don't know how to solve it. Please help!

My `Campaign.sol` file

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory{
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;
    function createCampaign(uint minimum)public{
        address newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
        deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }
    function getDeployedCampaign() public view returns(address[]){
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}

contract Campaign{
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
    }
    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    mapping (address => bool) public approvers;
    uint public approversCount;
    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    function Campaign (uint minimum, address creator)public{
        manager = creator;
        minimumContribution = minimum;
    }
    function contribue()public payable{
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
        approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        approversCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient)public restricted{
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            description: description,
            value: value,
            recipient: recipient,
            complete: false,
            approvalCount: 0
        });
        requests.push(newRequest); 
    }

    function approveRequest(uint index)public{
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(approvers[msg.sender]);
        require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

        request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
        request.approvalCount++;
    }
    function finalizeRequest(uint index)public restricted{
        Request storage request = requests[index];

        require(request.approvalCount > (approversCount/2));
        require(!request.complete);

        request.recipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;
    }

    function getSummary() public view returns (
        uint, uint, uint, uint, address
    ){
        return (
            minimumContribution,
            this.balance,
            requests.length,
            approversCount,
            manager
        );
    }

    function getRequestsCount() public view returns (uint){
        return requests.length;
    }
}
```

My `RequestRow.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Table, Button} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import web3 from '../ethereum/web3';
import Campaign from '../ethereum/campaign';

class RequestRow extends Component{
    onApprove = async() => {
        const campaign = Campaign(this.props.address);
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        await campaign.methods.approveRequest(this.props.id).send({
            from: accounts[0]
        });
    };
    onFinalize = async() => {
        const campaign = Campaign(this.props.address);
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        await campaign.methods.finalizeRequest(this.props.id).send({
            from: accounts[0]
        });
    };
    render(){
        const {Row, Cell} = Table;
        const {id, request, approversCount} = this.props;
        return (
            <Row>
                <Cell>{id}</Cell>
                <Cell>{request.description}</Cell>
                <Cell>{web3.utils.fromWei(request.value,'ether')}</Cell>
                <Cell>{request.recipient}</Cell>
                <Cell>{request.approvalCount}/{approversCount}</Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Button color="green" basic onClick={this.onApprove}>
                        Approve
                    </Button>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Button color="teal" basic onClick={this.onFinalize}>
                        Finalize
                    </Button>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default RequestRow;
```

The full error message that I got in the deveoper console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xcca9f6dac8c99c2ecc1f9314661399bda3a6096bf0f36d1c1724d84dcece42b2",
  "blockNumber": 5145820,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 270372,
  "from": "0x284aea2dca83c9c6247907554cb27120f7ce1892",
  "gasUsed": 55899,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x6ff70b2a9c30909431714902581539087fe25a3b",
  "transactionHash": "0x24b15e5db8bb673375409327cdde0fba98844126f5909ed7681845ee3bccce84",
  "transactionIndex": 2,
  "events": {}
}
    at index.js?959bf61:366
```

Comment: There are 2 `require` statements and a `restricted` modifier used in `finalizeRequest` solidity function. Maybe those conditions are failing.

Comment: @IftifarTaz Thanks for replying me. Do you mean that too many ```require``` statements may generate errors? I've used remix to check if my smart contract run correctly, remix doesn't return any error when I compile this contract.

Comment: No. I mean one of the require statements might be returning false. So transaction is reverted.

Comment: @IftifarTaz How can I know which require statement is wrong? By remix? Please help.

Comment: I've tried to test the require statement in remix, but still pops up the error as I use metamask. Can anyone guide me a way of solving it?

Comment: You can add a message to `require` to see which require failed. Ex: `require(msg.sender == manager, "Not nameger")`

Comment: @IftifarTaz I've tried your suggestion. However, still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey @Jessie, can you maybe try debugging the transaction with [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.dev/tx/rinkeby/0x24b15e5db8bb673375409327cdde0fba98844126f5909ed7681845ee3bccce84). When you click on **Debugger** you can follow the instructions on how to add the contract to a project and then you can get the exact line of code and reason why the transaction is failing. [Here is an example](https://dashboard.tenderly.dev/tx/main/0xc9056fac03f7bda82e514870aedee1dbd8f18c47ffeae3905b6f8520b164d24f) so you see how this can be useful to you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the rather complicated account switching required.

First, you need to create a campaign with one of your MetaMask accounts,
Then you need to create a request while in this same account as 'manager'.  When you copy and paste the address of the recipient make sure to switch back to the right account after, before submitting the request.

Then you need to contribute to the campaign with another MetaMask account, and approve the request while making sure you are still in the account that you contributed the funds with.

Normally this account switching would not be an issue but it is simulating multiple different users interacting with the contract.

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

you need use truffle/HDwallet and set provider.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions. There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts. This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer.